# React Admin: Is there a way to get what views are defined on a resource?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a custom Input component that customizes the render of an array of references. Some references have edit views defined in the `<Resource...>` section while others have only show views. Is there a way to determine if there is a defined view for the resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the react-admin Redux store contains that information. You should be able to get it via Redux' `useSelector`:

```
const { hasShow, hasEdit, hasList } = useSelector(state => state.admin.resources['posts'].props);
```